# NDSolve: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered?

Tags: differential-equations, broken-code

The following code give errors that I don't understand. 
Could you please suggest a method to solve these differential equations?

```
z2[Ω_, t_] := .01 Sin[Ω t](*External force*);
z1[Ω_, t_] := .01 Cos[ Ω t](*External force*);
m = 2350.0;
Ms = 7200.0 + 820.0;   
Js = 4000.0 + 7920.0*.25*.25;
l = 1.1;
h = 1.78;
hs = 0.19;
s = 2.413/2;
c = 1;
k = 358000*g;
g = 9.8;
Q = 2.0;
d = 2.4;
θ0 = ArcCos[l/d];
Ω = 26;

eqz = (m + Ms) g + 
   k (2 Z[t] - z1[Ω, t] - z2[Ω, t]) + l m Cos[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] (θ'[t])^2 + 
   2 l m Cos[θ[t] + ϕ[t]]θ'[t] ϕ'[t] + 
   (-h m Cos[ϕ[t]] + l m Cos[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] + Cos[ϕ[t]] hs Ms) (ϕ'[t])^2 + 
   c (2 Z'[t] - D[z1[Ω, t],t] - D[z2[Ω, t],t]) + m Z''[t] + Ms Z''[t] + 
   l m Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] θ''[t] + 
   (-h m Sin[ϕ[t]] + l m Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] + Sin[ϕ[t]] hs Ms) ϕ''[t];
eqϕ = -g h m Sin[ϕ[t]] + g l m Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] + 2 k s^2 ϕ[t] + 
      k s z1[Ω, t] - k s z2[Ω, t] + h l m Sin[θ[t]] (θ'[t])^2 + 
      2 c s^2 ϕ'[t] + 2 h l m Sin[θ[t]] θ'[t] ϕ'[t] + c s D[z1[Ω, t],t]- c s  D[z2[Ω, t],t] - h m Sin[ϕ[t]] Z''[t] + l m Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] Z''[t]+Sin[ϕ[t]] hs Ms Z''[t] + l^2 m θ''[t] - h l m Cos[θ[t]] θ''[t] + (m (h^2 + l^2 - 2 h l Cos[θ[t]]) + Js) ϕ''[t];

eqθ = Q θ'[t] + l m(g Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] - h Sin[θ[t]] (ϕ'[t])^2 + 
      l θ''[t] + (l - h Cos[θ[t]]) ϕ''[t]) + m l Z''[t] Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] +    
     (θ[t]/θ0)^5;


eq = {eqz == 0, eqϕ == 0, eqθ == 0};
inc = {Z[0] == (-(m + Ms) g)/(2 k), 
   Z'[0] == 0, ϕ[0] == 0, 
   ϕ'[0] == 0, θ[0] == 0, 
    θ'[0] == 0};
var = {Z[t], Z'[t], ϕ[t], 
   ϕ'[t], θ[t], 
    θ'[t]};
sol = {Z[t], ϕ[t], θ[t]} /. 
  NDSolve[{eq, inc}, var, {t, 0, 50}, MaxSteps -> ∞]
```

where `Z[t]` is a co-ordinate of motion.

the errors are as follows:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: …and without context of any sort, why should other people be interested in this?

Comment: Beware that `′` and `'` are not the same character. I have edited the question for that, but you just reverted that. Not sure why you copy&paste gives the wrong character.

Comment: @user37633mismatched ( right: eq\[Theta] = Q \[Theta]\[Prime][t] + l m ( <--here showing up in very pale red

Comment: in eqtheta I assume the `ltheta` should be `l theta`..?  Its a good idea to copy your own code back and make sure it runs.  After fixing up I get a different error than you report.

Comment: You can not use the prime notation with function of more than one varialble. ( Is `z2'[Ω, t]` supposed to be with respect to t or omega? )

Comment: Ok, with syntax issues fixed I find setting `theta[0]` initial condition to a small nonzero value yields a solution.

Comment: It would be nice to understand what is the physical meaning here of $\theta (0)$ to understand why an arbitrarily small value gives a solution but not zero. By the way, we could clean up the comments that have become obsolete so the question is readable and useful for future visitors.

Comment: due to nature of project, not able to give physical definition of terms. Though it is solvable with `theta[0]` having small nonzero value yet results are incorrect as value of `theta` can not be greater than 2.                            Another way of solving with zero initial conditions it is to use `Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` but still results does not adhere to above mentioned condition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too limited to the needs of the poster and is unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

```
z2[Ω_, t_] := Sin[Ω t]/100(*External force*);
z1[Ω_, t_] := Cos[Ω t]/100(*External force*);
m = 2350;
Ms = 7200 + 820;
Js = 4000 + 7920*1/4*1/4;
l = 11/10;
h = 178/100;
hs = 19/100;
s = 2413/2000;
c = 1;
k = 358000*g;
g = 98/10;
Q = 2;
d = 24/10;
θ0 = ArcCos[l/d];
Ω = 23;

eqz = (m + Ms) g + 
    k (2 Z[t] - z1[Ω, t] - z2[Ω, t]) + 
    l m Cos[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] (θ'[t])^2 + 
    2 l m Cos[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] θ'[t] ϕ'[
      t] + (-h m Cos[ϕ[t]] + l m Cos[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] + 
       Cos[ϕ[t]] hs Ms) (ϕ'[t])^2 + 
    c (2 Z'[t] - D[z1[Ω, t], t] - 
       D[z2[Ω, t], t]) + m Z''[t] + Ms Z''[t] + 
    l m Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] θ''[
      t] + (-h m Sin[ϕ[t]] + l m Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] + 
       Sin[ϕ[t]] hs Ms) ϕ''[t] // Simplify;

eqϕ = -g h m Sin[ϕ[t]] + g l m Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] + 
    2 k s^2 ϕ[t] + k s z1[Ω, t] - 
    k s z2[Ω, t] + h l m Sin[θ[t]] (θ'[t])^2 + 
    2 c s^2 ϕ'[t] + 2 h l m Sin[θ[t]] θ'[t] ϕ'[t] + 
    c s D[z1[Ω, t], t] - c s D[z2[Ω, t], t] - 
    h m Sin[ϕ[t]] Z''[t] + l m Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] Z''[t] + 
    Sin[ϕ[t]] hs Ms Z''[t] + l^2 m θ''[t] - 
    h l m Cos[θ[t]] θ''[
      t] + (m (h^2 + l^2 - 2 h l Cos[θ[t]]) + Js) ϕ''[t] // 
   Simplify;

eqθ = 
  Q θ'[t] + 
    l m (g Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] - h Sin[θ[t]] (ϕ'[t])^2 + 
       l θ''[t] + (l - h Cos[θ[t]]) ϕ''[t]) + 
    m l Z''[t] Sin[θ[t] + ϕ[t]] + (θ[t]/θ0)^5 // 
   Simplify;

eq = {eqz == 0, eqϕ == 0, eqθ == 0};
inc = {Z[0] == (-(m + Ms) g)/(2 k), 
   Z'[0] == 0, ϕ[0] == 10^-12, ϕ'[0] == 0, θ[0] == 
    0, θ'[0] == 0};
var = {Z[t], Z'[t], ϕ[t], ϕ'[t], θ[t], θ'[t]};

sol = {Z[t], ϕ[t], θ[t]} /. 
   NDSolve[{eq, inc}, var, {t, 0, 50}, MaxSteps -> ∞][[1]];
```

The maximum value of θ[t] is

```
Maximize[{sol[[3]], 0 <= t <= 50}, t, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(*  {0.172713, {t -> 15.7206}}  *)
```

Looking at `sol`

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[sol], {t, 0, tmax},
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 200,
  PlotRange -> {-0.2, 0.2},
  PlotLegends -> {Z[t], ϕ[t], θ[t]}],
 {{tmax, 20, Subscript[t, max]}, .1, 50, .1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: @MarcoB, this is valid for omega = 23 but not omega =26, it should be valid for any omega.